# log post and get parameters in nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging

I'm trying to make simple logger for nodejs to handle post and get request also, but I've got problem, because of the non blocking feature of node-js, the parameters is print after the system print the response log here is my code

```
process.stdout.write(createReqFormat(req));

if(req.method !== 'GET') {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
    process.stdout.write('\n Parameters:' + util.inspect(fields));
  });
}

res.on('finish', function(){
  process.stdout.write(createResFormat(res));
});
next();
```

for now I only print parameter for post parameter, but this already killing me.

```
Started POST /post for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Apr 27 2015 09:08:36 GMT+0700 (WIB)
Completed 200 OK
Parameters:{ one: '1', kals: '123', test: '1233', 'test[123]': 'dfjksdjf' }
```

how to make it print in the right order?

thank you

Comment: Can you put the entire code for your request handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the form can actually take more time than finishing the response, so don't call `next` (or `res.send`) until you're done with the form.

```
process.stdout.write(createReqFormat(req));

res.on('finish', function(){
  process.stdout.write(createResFormat(res));
});

if(req.method !== 'GET') {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
    if (err) return next(err);
    process.stdout.write('\n Parameters:' + util.inspect(fields));
    next();
  });
} else {
  next();
}
```